# Javascript: Dynamically generated functions, referring to an external included JS File with GPT rendering

Tags: javascript, dynamic, external, google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

Thanks for looking at this. I think I am making a conceptional mistake in my thoughts, that's why I will let you know about my scenario first:

I have 1 or x DIVs where I display DFP AdUnits and will use these dynamically generated functions on. The function triggers as soon as the DIV is in a visible area:

1. I generate the links dynamically

```js
  function scriptincluder(divid){
    var gbgscript = document.createElement('script');
    gbgscript.async = true;
    gbgscript.type = 'text/javascript';
    gbgscript.src = 'https://anyscript.net/script.js?function=myfmydiv1&div=mydiv1 ';
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(gbgscript, node);
  }
```

With this function I dynamically create the link and this works so far. So I generate links for myfmydiv1/div1, myfmydiv2/div2, myfmydiv3/div3… so on. And add them to the parentNode.

2. I generate the AdSlots dynamically

```js
 googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        for (var slot in divslots) {
                window['slot_'.concat(slot.toString())] = googletag.defineSlot('/Adslot/Adslot/Adslot/Adslot/Adslot/Adslot', slotsize[slot], slot.toString()).addService(googletag.pubads());

                // generate external link pixel from #1:
                scriptincluder(slot.toString());
        }
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();  // ad unit will not render yet
        googletag.enableServices();
    });
```

In this part I generate the Ad Units and add it to a global variable "window['slot_'.concat(slot.toString())]" (<== I have seen this on the web and I am curious if that's the right way to go. At least I can see it in the GCR dev. tool)

3. I generate the functions referring to the link at #1 dynamically.

```js
  for (var slot in divslots) {
    var [‘myf’ + escape(slot)] = function() { 
        alert("I am: " + slot);
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.pubads().refresh([window['slot_'.concat(key2.toString())]]);});
    }
  }
```

The function is triggered once the DIV slot is in a visible area and refreshes the Ad Unit.

It always triggers the wrong function. For example, div1 triggers function of div2 and div1 doesn’t actually load, but div2. Any ideas/help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution with an experienced programmer colleague of mine.
He suggested to use the **cont variable** for the variable function in the last piece of code.

```js
  for (var slot in divslots) {
    
    const myFunction = 'myf' + escape(slot);
    const mySlot = 'slot_'.concat(slot.toString());
  
    var [myFunction] = function() { 
        alert("I am: " + slot);
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.pubads().refresh([window[mySlot]]);});
    }
  }
```